# can App Engine SDK run on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

The question may sound a bit stupid but I think it's interesting.  Is it possible to upload a GAE application (java or python) from another GAE application ? I mean to use the first GAE app purely as a build server (e.g. http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview ) to build / deploy an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds interesting to me, but ultimately I'm not sure of the practicality of it.  You'd have to spend quite a bit of effort to modify the SDK to replace all file operations, and emulate the development filesystem on either the filestore or blobstore.

I say I don't think it's practical, because unless you're running strictly as backends (which ends up being expensive), none of the frontends really last long enough to emulate a debugger.  It would be very difficult to develop software if you can't debug.

That and what Nick said.

Answer (score 1):

It would be technically possible to do this with some tweaking, but the Terms of Service prohibit apps that upload other apps.

Comment: Is there any reason for that ?(TOS prohibit) I would like to develop an amazing development tool and automatic deployment directly from the online IDE itself  not "bots" or evil stuff .

Comment: Probably a spam prevention measure. You say "amazing development tool and automatic deployment" they hear "content farm generator".

Comment: @arkanciscan yeah but I presume they would have a look on the app before to terminate it. As it would be amazing I think it will have chances to not get terminated ?! Regarding the prohibition I think anything can be used to do harm (e.g. the email service may be used to spam ). I would be able to upload the apps automatically from an external server anyway so I don't get the prohibition .